# Does the enlarge/reduce spell change a target’s weight?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

So my party came up with an idea for how they would start the siege on the goblin camp. Their thought was to cast *reduce* on the gnome barbarian, tie him to an arrow and shoot him over the wall, then drop concentration and cast *enlarge* on him on the other side.

My question is whether the gnome would weigh down the arrow too much, or when he shrinks does he get lighter, making it possible to fire the arrow?

Comment: I think you are getting downvotes here because it says so [right in the first sentence of the reduce effect in the spell description](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/enlarge-reduce), which would be reasonable and little effort to read when you want to know what the spell does.

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin: Yeah, I only bothered to answer to provide feedback on the practical application for this for gnome barbarian launching they were looking at. I didn't down-vote, but the basic answer (eight-fold weight reduction) was trivially available to them.

Answer (score 9):

Yeah, it says so in the spell:

> **Reduce.** The target's size is halved in all dimensions, and its weight is reduced to one-eighth of normal.

Whether that makes him light enough to be fired by an arrow, is up to the DM. The Gnome might still be too heavy (especially with heavy gear). But he does drop in weight proportionally to his new size.

Comment: "*But he does drop in weight proportionally to his new size.*" for clarification, that is by following the [square-cube law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square%E2%80%93cube_law), roughly: a 3D shape that grows by a square of its size (or surface area) also grows by a cube of its weight (technically volume but then that is often close enough with 1:1 to weight). Reduce is just trying to apply the law in the opposite direction - it's reducing the size by half and reducing the weight by half to the power of negative three (total of 1/8).

Answer (score 4):

As the spell says (emphasis added):

> The target's size is halved in all dimensions, and **its weight is reduced to one-eighth of normal**.

According to the character details section, **a gnome weighs 35 + 2d4 lbs.** (technically, they're 2'11" +2d4 inches tall, and each inch adds one poind), for a range of 37-43 lbs., **which would round off to ~5 lbs when reduced.**

That's light, but it's still insanely heavy for an arrow; **arrows are considered "heavy" at or above 460 grains of weight, which is just over an *ounce* (~30 grams metric)**; the range of weights for reasonable weight arrows is only a few hundred grains at most. Even half a pound would be absurdly overweight for an arrow, but perhaps acceptable in a heroic fantasy game like D&D. **Unless you can somehow reduce your size twice over, to get down to 1/64th of your original weight, you're going to be too heavy.**

Suggestion: **If you want to do something like this in a siege scenario, and your DM is okay with nonsensical hijinks like this** (the process of launching you would be almost as traumatic as the process of landing, and living bodies are rather less tough than typical ammunition), **bring along siege weaponry.** Typical historical Roman ballistae could launch a one talent (26 kg/57 lb) stone ~500 yards; your gnome is likely less aerodynamic, but they're light enough to be launched even without being reduced. Catapults & trebuchet can launch even more weight, at higher arcs.

As I said, this makes *zero* sense; for all practical purposes, you should be taking falling damage equivalent to at least half the range of the weapon (one could be generous and make it based on the actual distance traveled, assuming you reduced the tension before firing), which for most useful siege distances, likely means taking the maximum falling damage, 20d6. But if that's okay with you, or your DM lets you get away with some much lower damage (I'd say the *absolute* minimum should be the damage the weapon would deal if hit by it, 3d10 for a ballista), have fun, go nuts!

Comment: For any buddding DMs out there, if a character ever wants to get launched from a siege weapon - let them!

Comment: @SeriousBri: Yeah, I think there should be some consequence (I'd probably go with "you take damage equal to what the weapon deals" approach rather than using falling damage, e.g. 3d10, not 20d6, and if they have access to Feather Fall, let that negate it [they'd likely be out of range from friendly casters, so they'd need to be able to cast it]), but I wouldn't make it so deadly that it's entirely non-viable at almost any level (20d6 falling damage is a *lot*). Of course, it would depend on the seriousness level of the game; in a Dark Sun game, you'd die twice over if you tried it. :-)